# Getting 'cannot list resource "pods/var"' from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

I am trying to set up fluent-bit in a custom namespace. I took the following steps (lots ellided here for clarity):

I created the serviceaccount like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: k8s-logger
  namespace: efk
```

Then I bound that serviceaccount to the standard "view" ClusterRrole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: k8s-logger
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: k8s-logger
  namespace: efk
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Finally, I created the fluent-bit DaemonSet and told it to use the "k8s-logger" ServiceAccount:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: efk
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccount: k8s-logger
      serviceAccountName: k8s-logger
.
.
.
```

(As an aside, if anyone know the difference between serviceAccount and serviceAccountName I'd be interested to learn).

However, I got the following output in the fluent-bit logs:

```
pods is forbidden: User "system.serviceaccount:efk:k8s-logger" cannot list resource "pods/var" in API group "" in the namespace "work"
```

When it didn't work, I started verifying:

- Fluent-bit is connecting using the custom ServiceAccount:
  I believe it is because the error message references `system.serviceaccount:efk:k8s-logger`
- The serviceaccount exists and is in the correct namespace:

  ```
  $ kubectl get serviceaccounts/k8s-logging --namespace=efk
  NAME        SECRETS   AGE
  k8s-logger  1         15h
  ```
- The ClusterRoleBinding is correct (references the correct ServiceAccount and ClusterRole):

  ```
  $ kubectl describe clusterrolebinding/k8s-logging
  Name:         k8s-logger
  Labels:       <none>
  Annotations:  <none>
  Role:
    Kind:  ClusterRole
    Name:  view
  Subjects:
    Kind            Name        Namespace
    ----            ----        ---------
    ServiceAccount  k8s-logger  efk
  ```
- Finally, verify that the default role "view" has the permissions I need:

  ```
  $ kubectl describe clusterrole/view
  Name:       view
  Labels:     kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
  PolicyRule:
    Resources           Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names  Verbs
    ---------           -----------------   --------------  -----
    pods                []                  []              [get list watch]
    pods/log            []                  []              [get list watch]
    pods/status         []                  []              [get list watch]
    .
    .
    .
  ```

At this point I do not know how to debug further or to figure out what the problem is. I flailed about by:

- creating a custom ClusterRole with the permissions I need (just in case view doesn't work the way I thought it does)
- Using only either serviceAccount or serviceAccountName in the DaemonSet spec (just in case one of those breaks the other)

but these things didn't change anything. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says `cannot list resource "pods/var"` -- and as a disclaimer: I've never seen that RBAC resource ever.

While the `view` ClusterRole, grants you read privileges over:

```
pods                []                  []              [get list watch]
pods/log            []                  []              [get list watch]
pods/status         []                  []              [get list watch]
```

Try to create your own ClusterRole, adding `pods/var` to that list, assuming that's a thing? `pods/log`, `pods/status`, or `pods/exec` are more common, though based on that error, I guess `pods/var` is a thing?

One way to go about this would be to duplicate the `view` role, and add what you need:

```
kubectl get -o yaml clusterrole view >my-view-role.yaml
vi my-view-role.yaml
```

Reset its metadata, and rename the clusterrole, remove the aggregationRules if any:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: view-plus
rules:
[...]
```

Keep the original rules in, locate a mentions of pods/status or pods/log, and insert pods/var, as suggested by your error message:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - bindings
  - events
  - limitranges
  - namespaces/status
  - pods/log
  - pods/status
  - pods/var
  - replicationcontrollers/status
  - resourcequotas
  - resourcequotas/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Create that ClusterRole, `kubectl create -f ...`

Next, replace your ClusterRoleBinding, using your custom ClusterRole.

Comment: That was exactly it. It was confusing because I have never heard of pods/var either, and the error message talked about "pods is forbidden", so I didn't try it.